# how to edit this vba code to create lines in excel

Tags: excel, vba

My last post was about editing a VBA code to create the header of a file that i’m using for electronic payments.
Today’s problem would be about modifying a code to create lines associated with the header.
So first, I’ll explain the format of the line :
The line is 62 characters long :

1. A star at the begining (*) of each line,
2. The account number which is 20 characters long (no more than that), for example if a cell in excel contains the account number, let’s say 300034 and another cell contains the key associated with the account, let’s say 70, the line to this stage woulld be *00000000000030003470.
3. the amounts that a client will receive, (no more than 13 characters), for example if a cell contains 30759.25, than the line until now would look like this :
   *000000000000300034700000003075925
   If the amount is 99999999999.99 then the line would look like this :
   *000000000000300034709999999999999
4. the name of the client (no more than 27 characters), if the name is joseph david, it means that there is 12 characters including the space between « joseph » and « david », so the line created thus far would look like this :
   *000000000000300034709999999999999joseph david               1
   With 15 spaces after david to each 27 characters, and then the number (1) at the end of the line to reach 62 characters of the line.
   The code that i have does not limit the size of names, accounts, amounts.
   The code is :

   ```
   Public Function Lines(Account, Key, Amount, Name As String) As String

   'Account
   C1 = Len(Account)
   C1 = (18 - C1)
   For i = 1 To C1
   M = M & "0"
   Next
   C1 = M & Account

   'Key
   If Key = "" Then
      Key = "00"
   ElseIf Key < 10 Then
      Key = "0" & Key
   Else
      Key = Key
   End If

   'Amount
   Amount = Amount * 100
   C2 = Len(Amount)
   C2 = (13 - C2)
   For i = 1 To C2
   M1 = M1 & "0"
   Next
   C2 = M1 & Amount

   'Nen & PréName
   C3 = Name

   'Annee
   C4 = "*" & C1 & Key & C2 & C3

   'CD ZERO
   C5 = Len(C4)
   C5 = (61 - C5)
   For i = 1 To C5
   M3 = M3 & " "
   Next
   C5 = C4 & M3

   Lines = C5 & "1"

   End Function
   ```

thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if the name of the customer exceeds 27 characters?

Comment: FunThomas
 truncate it in the last 27 character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Public Function Lines(Account As String, Key As String, Amount as Double, Name As String) As String
    Const accountLen = 20
    Const amountLen = 13
    Const nameLen = 27

    Lines = "*" _
          & Right(String(accountLen, "0") & Account & Key, accountLen) _
          & Format(Amount * 100, String(amountLen, "0")) _
          & Left(Right(Name, nameLen) & String(nameLen, " "), nameLen) _
          & "1"
End Function
```

The `String` function creates a String that contains a number of characters, eg `String(20, "0")` creates a string "00000000000000000000".

For the **Account**, we concatenate this 20 zeros with the account and the key and take the rightmost 20 characters - that gives the account & key with leading zeros.

For the **Amount**, I assume we have a numeric value, and we can use the `Format` function to create leading zeros and 2 decimals. **Update**: Changed this as OP don't want decimal comma (or point).

For the **Name**, we take the rightmost 27 characters plus 27 spaces and take 27 characters from the left of the result - that gives the name with trailing blanks.

Comment: FunThomas
The amount should not contain (.) in the decimal part
For example 25256.25 should look like this :
0000002525625

Comment: Already updated

Comment: @snollygoster, don't forget to click `accept` if this answered your question.

Comment: FunThomas
the name when it exceeds 27 characters should be truncated at the last character, not at the beginning

Comment: Replace 'Right(Name, nameLen)' with 'Left(Name, nameLen)' should do the trick (cannot test at the moment)